# How can I handle input in C without halting the main loop?

Tags: input, game-loop, c, text-based

I want my C program to update the console every second, and it was working fine until I tried to handle input. Now the program halts since it waits an input from the user. How can I do this?

```
while(true) {
    ShowConsole();  //Show
    Sleep(1000);        //Wait
    scanf("%s",&a)      //Handle Input  
    Update();
    ClearScreen();      //Clear
}
```

Comment: Have you consulted past Q&A on the topic, such as [How do you implement input handling in a C game engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/62572/39518)?

Comment: A word of advise: The C console is useful for doing some basic text IO while you are learning the absolute basics of the language, but it is rather inadequate for game development. So when making games is your goal, then you should not bother too much with `stdio.h` and learn a game development library for input handling and graphics instead. Like [SDL](https://libsdl.org), for example.

Comment: I think it's a legitimate question, and it has been asked (and answered) [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875136/continuous-keyboard-input-in-c) before.

Comment: Isn't it really just a "which technology to use" question though? The answer boils down to "use an input handling library" which then leads to "which?"

Comment: @MaximusMinimus This is sort of a grey zone. We can often turn "which technology to use to do X" into "How do I do X", which then should be answered by "You can use Library W to achieve this, here is how: [code here]".

Comment: The question is technically not gamedev specific because people have been wring console apps for ages--so it should probably be closed because "should ask on SO"--but I haven't closed it yet because I thought a game developers could have a better perspective to offer.

Comment: On Linux at least, you can make use non-blocking mode. (not with `scanf`; you have to use `read`)

Comment: @AliTeo: Console or terminal things aren't as unified as the higher level stuff. There's still a lot of boiler plate things to do. Have a look at the example of the life program in J. Gustedt's book "Modern C", that has asynchronous input as well, example source code somewhere (search and find). I have no idea for Windows, it might work too, though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty to try and tackle this myself.

Solely based on the question text, it's not super clear what kind of game you're trying to do, so I took the approach of a kind of *snake* game, where the snake will move, whatever the player is doing (or not doing).

I used `Sleep` to pace the input polling and the redraw rate, and `_kbhit()` to *maybe* read a character, and the `clock_t`/`clock()` to update the game once per second.

Now I'm not a `c` programmer, so I don't know if this `c` code is "elegant" (it's probably not), but it worked on my machine (Windows, Visual Studio).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef int BOOL;
#define FALSE ((int)0)
#define TRUE ((int)1)

void ClearScreen()
{
  // code here that clears the screen, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42500322
}

int main( void )
{
  BOOL run = TRUE;

  clock_t lastTickClock = clock();
  int position = 0;

  char registeredCommand = 'd'; // Command that will be effective at the next game tick.
  while ( run )
  {
    char currentCharIfAny = 0; // The char that is read this loop.
    if ( _kbhit() )
      currentCharIfAny = _getch();

    if ( currentCharIfAny == 'a' || currentCharIfAny == 'd' )
      registeredCommand = currentCharIfAny; // We only respond to 'a' or 'd'.

    clock_t newClock = clock();
    if ( ( newClock - lastTickClock ) > CLOCKS_PER_SEC )
    {
      // This is the command handling/the game tick
      if ( registeredCommand == 'a' )
        position = max( --position, 0 );
      else if ( registeredCommand == 'd' )
        position = min( ++position, 24 );

      lastTickClock = newClock;
    }

    char buffer[1024];
    buffer[0] = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < position; ++i )
      strcat_s( buffer, 1024, " " );
    strcat_s( buffer, 1024, "_\n" ); // This underscore represents our "agent" or "game token" or "paddle".

    // The following is only for debugging purpose; it prints the character we're currently handling. 
    if ( currentCharIfAny >= 'a' && currentCharIfAny <= 'z' )
    {
      char lbuff[2]; lbuff[0] = 0;
      sprintf_s( lbuff, 2, "%c", currentCharIfAny );
      strcat_s( buffer, 1024, lbuff );
    }

    ClearScreen();
    printf( "%s\n", buffer );
    Sleep( 1000 / 60 );
    if ( currentCharIfAny == 'q' )
      run = FALSE;
  }

  printf( "\ndone. press a key to quit." );
  _getch();
  return 0;
}
```

A couple of things to note:

- there are probably other (better) ways to achieve this: for now, when I refresh (ClearScreen), the screen "flickers" a bit.
- on Windows, the OS will "pace" the repeat rate of the character it sends to the apps, so when you hit <kbd>d</kbd> for instance, the program will show that you're hitting <kbd>d</kbd>, then it will show that you're hitting no key, then it will show you're hitting <kbd>d</kbd> again, until you release the key.
- like your own implementation, it's not portable due to the nature of the functions used.

Answer (score 0):

Although I had to use non-portable code, I got it to work without a need of a third-party  library. Also it turns out _kbhit() function delays buffer so you do not need to wait for 1 second to enter the full string. However the written string was being cut if it is not written in a second. So I also showed it in ShowConsole() function.

Note: This is a non-standart, non-portable code. Works in my OS (Windows).

```
char key;
    if(_kbhit()){
        key = _getch();
        if(key == 13){                  //If Enter key is pressed
            HandleInput(moveInput);     //handle the input string
            memset(moveInput, 0, 6);    //clear input string
            moveIndex=0;                //reset string index to 0
        }
        moveInput[moveIndex] = key;     //If any other key is pressed, add the hit character to string input
        moveIndex++;
    }
```

In ShowConsole() Function:

```
ShowConsole(){
    .
    .
    .
    printf("%s", moveInput); // At the end of showing the graphics, also show the input that is being written.
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the issue that you have (or don't have) regarding "1 second"? Do you still have the sleep?

Comment: @Vaillancourt Yes, I do have the sleep function still because I am updating the Console every second. Update: I changed it after I saw your answer, now I simply use clock().